# Create nested subgroup with timevis in R

Tags: r, timeline, vis.js, htmlwidgets

I want to create a timeline like [this one](http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/groups/nestedGroups.html) using `R`'s `timevis` package.
I know how to build a group as they do in the demo:

```
library(timevis)

dataGroups <- data.frame(
  id = 1:11,
  content = c(
    "Open",
    "Open",
    "Open",
    "Open",
    "Half price entry",
    "Staff meeting",
    "Open",
    "Adults only",
    "Open",
    "Hot tub closes",
    "Siesta"
  ),
  start = c(
    "2016-05-01 07:30:00",
    "2016-05-01 14:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 06:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 14:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 08:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 08:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 08:30:00",
    "2016-05-01 14:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 16:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 19:30:00",
    "2016-05-01 12:00:00"
  ),
  end   = c(
    "2016-05-01 12:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 20:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 12:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 22:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 10:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 08:30:00",
    "2016-05-01 12:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 16:00:00",
    "2016-05-01 20:00:00",
    NA,
    "2016-05-01 14:00:00"
  ),
  group = c(rep("lib", 2), rep("gym", 3), rep("pool", 5), NA),
  subgroup = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", NA),
  type = c(rep("range", 9), "point", "background")
)

groups <- data.frame(id = c("lib", "gym", "pool"),
                     content = c("Library", "Gym", "Pool"))

timevis(
  data = dataGroups,
  groups = groups,
  options = list(editable = TRUE, stack = FALSE)
)
```

I don't know how to include the subgroups in the final timeline. 
I believe it might be possible using `setGroups` or including some options using `htmlwidgets::JS()`. I was trying the examples in the docs using the second option and it doesn't seem to work:

```
timevis(
  data.frame(
    id = 1,
    content = "double click anywhere<br>in the timeline<br>to add an item",
    start = "2016-01-01"
  ),
  options = list(
    editable = TRUE,
    onAdd = htmlwidgets::JS(
      'function(item, callback) {
      item.content = "Hello!<br/>" + item.content;
      timevis 19
      callback(item);
      }'
    )
  )
)
```

Any example of a timeline including subgroups would be appreciated.

In case this feature can't be used in `R` is there an alternative available?

Comment: (1) I don't understand either if you want `subgroup`s or `nestedGroups`. (2) the line `timevis 19`  in your `onAdd()` javascript snippet breaks the code.

Answer (score 2):

I guess maybe you are confusing *subGroups* with *nestedGroups*. Subgroups are used to show events in different levels within the same category. If you change your `subgroup` attribute to this:

```
subgroup = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "D", "D", "F", "E", "F", NA)
```

You would be able to see (in the below timeline):

- One subgroup (`A`) for **Library** (you notice that the events are in the same horizontal level)
- Two subgroups (`B` & `C`) for **Gym** (you notice that the events are distributed into two horizontal levels)
- Three subgroups (`D`, `E`, & `F`) for **Pool** (you notice that the events are distributed into three horizontal levels)

[image: TimeVis with Subgroups]

The link you've provided contains a timeline that is generated using the Javascript version of `timvis`, which supports having *nestedGroups* in the timeline. If you open the [source](http://view-source:http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/groups/nestedGroups.html) of that page, you will be able to see how is that implemented.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understood the difference between nestedGroups and subGroups. My question is if they can be implemented in `R`. I included the last piece of code because it seems that some features can be added using `options` and I'm wondering if nested groups is one of those features.

Comment: That is just to add EventListeners to the plotted timeline I believe. You may not be able to draw something in there.

Comment: You may have a look at the available options here: http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options